# Get the trim value from the double value

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

i have the values like 1.2344,2.3455,3.45666 and 6.45667,Now i want convert this like 2.0,3.0,4.0 and 7.0.so can any Help me to do this.i tried with another codes but no one is not satisfying my actual requirement.

Comment: Are they `NSString`s or `double`s? Have you tried using `ceil(...)`? Can you provide some example code of something you have tried that doesn't work?

Comment: `ceilf` is what you want, then just use %.1f if gives a load of 00 at the end

Comment: yes friends,ceil is working thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to round a number up.

`ceilf`  is what you want, it will return a float so you want to use that to one decimal place.

```
NSLog(@"ceilf %.1f", ceilf(1.23456));

2015-03-06 14:42:39.537 [xxxx] ceilf 2.0
```

Comment: thank you MR.@BooRanger.some bodies are commented on my question use ceil but send the code also